# Ternary operation in check/in checking HTML checkbox

Tags: checkbox, operator-keyword, ternary

My JavaScript spits out dynamic HTML with one of the fields as checkbox based on a boolean as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled='true' (bool == true ? "Checked":"undefined") />
```

My checkbox always returns checked even if the Boolean is false .
Any suggestions to doing that by ternary operation?

Also i just realized that it would be hard to have id's for each row of checkboxes. Here is how my function currently looks like:

function fnBuildWebSiteClipHtml(name, url, id, allow_removal, use_full_screen) {

```
var html = "<tr id='wc_" + id + "'>" +
    tdstart + "<div style='float: left; width: 20px'><img src='/emm/websiteIcon.do?id="+id+"' height='16px' width='16px'/></div><div style='float: left; vertical-align: middle;'>" + OrionCore.escapeHtml(name) + "</div></td>" +
    tdstart + OrionCore.escapeHtml(url) + "</td>" +
    tdstart + "<input type='checkbox' disabled='true' " + (allow_removal ? "checked='true'" : "") + "/>" + "</td>" +
    tdstart + "<input type='checkbox' disabled='true' " + (use_full_screen ? "checked='true'" : "") + "/>" + "</td>" +
    tdstart +
    "<table>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<td><a href='javascript:fnShowWebsiteclip(" + id + ")'>"+MESSAGES.edit+"</a> | </td>" +
    "<td><a href='javascript:fnDeleteWebsiteclip(" + id + ")'>"+MESSAGES.del +"</a></td>" +
    "</tr>" +
    "</table>" +
    "</td>" +
    "</tr>";
return html;
```

}

Line 8 where i check the allow_removal and then following line with check for use_full_screen is what i am trying to have my checkboxes follow. Any suggestions towards that are much appreciated.

Thanks for an already posted response but i am not sure how to fit that here in this situation.

Comment: how do you set your bool variable?

Comment: Both are read from database and another function passes these as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need it?

```
<body onload="(bool ==true) ? document.getElementById('myTernaryCheckBox').setAttribute('checked', 'checked')  : false">
<input type="checkbox" disabled id="myTernaryCheckBox"/>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried this one but not able to fit into my function. Unless i assign id's for the multiple rows of checkboxes.